# Import csv without column names

Tags: import, csv

I need to import articles from a non magento csv file which does not contain any column names. How can I tell the import that product name is in column 1? Anyway todo this without changing the csv every time?

Comment: You can make a simple php (or you can choose the programming language) that adds an extra row at the top of the file. This way you don't have to edit it every time. Just run a command line. I think it's easier and safer than modifying the Magento import. Modifying a file is one of the basic operations in any programming language.

Comment: Do you want to do the import via the upload in the backend or would an own import script be okay?

Comment: @Alex Backend would be great but it looks like I need to write something myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [AvS_FastSimpleImport](https://github.com/avstudnitz/AvS_FastSimpleImport/). It is a thin layer on top of the standard import function and reads the data from arrays you have to provide.

Converting the CSV you have to the pre-defined array structure (which is just the same as in the import CSV files which Magento expects) should be easy.

In addition it can create drop-down attributes on the fly and has some bug fixes, as far as I know.

There is also a [German blog-post](http://www.avs-webentwicklung.de/nc/blog/artikel/magento-import-mit-der-neuen-schnellen-import-schnittstelle-fuer-produkte-und-kunden.html) about the module.